# Render menu separately within admin

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I need to render the main menu within the admin section of my website.  I am setting up a module to do this on a new page.  I need to theme this menu custom for just the admin, and leave it as it typically would be on the front-end of the site.

How can do do this?

```
$menu = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
// ...customize template/output for this menu and render from my module...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these method.

Below method is used to print Main Menu in [page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7.x) file:

```
$main_menu = menu_navigation_links('main-menu');
$output = '<div id="main-menu" class="navigation">';
$output .= theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
    'links' => $main_menu,
    'attributes' => array(
      'id' => 'main-menu-links',
      'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
    ),
    'heading' => array(
      'text' => t('Main menu'),
      'level' => 'h2',
      'class' => array('element-invisible'),
    ),
  ));
$output .= '</div>';
print $output;
```

Or the example provided [here](https://api.drupal.org/comment/50288#comment-50288):

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
menu_tree_add_active_path($tree);
print drupal_render(menu_tree_output($tree));
```